# How to enable redirection in Volley NetworkImageView?

Tags: android, redirect, android-volley, networkimageview

I am using Volley NetworkImageView to display images in my Android app. The image endpoint may return HTTP 200 + image or HTTP 303 + redirect URL.

I searched Volley documents but didn't find a way to enable redirection in a NetworkImageView.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it better to use a [gilde](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load photos?

Or use Gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

use in activity or anything :

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.imageload)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Just as easily